# Flyweights with Boost and external data sources

Tags: c++, boost, flyweight-pattern, boost-flyweight

Maybe there is a simple way around this that I'm not seeing, so hopefully somebody can explain it to me.

Let's say I have a class:

```
class A {
public:
  const double parameter;
  const std::string name;
  const std:: string fileName;

  A(const double parameter, const std::string name, const std::string fileName) : 
      parameter(parameter), name(name), fileName(fileName) {}; 
};
```

And the generator for that class is:

```
class AReader {
public:
  ifstream dataFile;
  AReader(const std::string filename);
  A* readObject(const std::string objectName);
};
```

I would like to use `boost::flyweight` to handle these `A` objects because there will be potentially millions of references to them and in reality they contain a lot of data. They will be hashed on `name` and `fileName` together.

What do I need to make this work? I need the `boost::flyweight` to call `AReader.readObject` and hash/store the resulting `A` class.

Does the `AReader` need to become a full factory and used as a custom factory? Or is it possible to use the default factory in the flyweight and somehow use `AReader` to generate the `A` instances (as opposed to implementing the entire storage pattern required by the factory), maybe by making an `AReader` instance an argument to something in the flyweight? Or is it possible to get `const` public variables (ie. once set, they don't change) from an external data source without resorting to a second class?

**Edit**

I'm also open to other suggestions not using Boost. I can certainly write my own implementation of a flyweight, or any other pattern if one is better suited. But if I can use something that already exists, that would be best. Whatever minimizes the amount of code I need to write because, as always, deadlines are short.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Boost::flyweight but from the looks of it at the very least the key needs to be `Assignable` (in addition to being `EqualityComparable` and `Hashable`). With your `const` members you type is clearly **not** `Assignable`. From the looks of it, you don't have to make it `Assignable` if you have a *key extractor*. Using a key extractor only the key needs to be `Assignable`.

Comment: That handles what needs to be done to get `A` into the flyweight (key extractor rather than assignable), but is the only way to use a helper-class that generates `A` to make it a full-blown factory to be used by the flyweight (implementing the storage and other methods required)?

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to use flyweight in your case is for readObject to return a flyweight. 
Internally, readObject creates a brand new object, and when you create the corresponding flyweight object, it then checks whether the object is already within the flyweight store. If so, it will drop your new object, and return a flyweight referencing the object in the store. If not, it adds the new object to its pool.

Now, this should be trivial to implement, but depending on your use case could be inefficient. For better performances, you can use the [key_value](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/key_value.html) functionality, which allows you to reference objects through their key, and only create them if they are not already present in the store.

Answer (score 0):

Although a `key_value` Flyweight seems to fit the bill, it would seem there's a minor hitch.
You should be able to construct a `key_value` Flyweight by using just one parameter of the key type ([key_value flyweights](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/key_value.html)). So to make it work with the key you want (filename+name) you'd have to pack those 2 fields in one ([tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html)? not even sure that'd work.)

Assuming you're interested in getting the most with the least amount of work, why not just `Flyweight` the strings in your class as demonstrated in [Flyweight Basics](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/basics.html)?

This means `A` objects aren't hashed the way you want, but strings are easily flyweighted, and these *seem* to be your memory-problematic fields. (unless this is an oversimplification)